# SQL join query (joined field as a json object)

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, pg

I'm using PostgreSQL and I'm using Nodejs and PG package. I have these tables:

request_tbl:

```
 req_id |  customer_id  | details              
----+--------------------------------------
  1     |    1          | something
```

customers_tbl:

```
 cust_id |  full_name | age             
----+--------------------------------------
  1      |  tarik hh  | 23
```

I need a query that gives this output after converting it to json.

It's a left join but I need the joined columns as an Object.

```
  [
    {
       "req_id":"1" , 
       "details":"something" ,
       "customer":{
                    "cust_id":"1",
                    "full_name":"tarik hh"
                  }
    }
      
  ]
```

Comment: Avoid posting the solution to your question in the question's body. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use postgresql's built in `json_build_object` function and create your own function like so:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_req_w_cust(
  req_id_in int, 
  out results json
) AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT json_build_object(
    'req_id', request_tbl.req_id,
    'details', request_tbl.details,
    'customer', json_build_object(
      'cust_id', customers_tbl.cust_id,
      'full_name', customers_tbl.full_name
    )
  ) INTO results
  FROM request_tbl, customers_tbl
    WHERE request_tbl.customer_id = customers_tbl.cust_id
    AND request_tbl.req_id = req_id_in
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you can access it from your code with

```
let {rows: [{results}] = await pg.query('select get_req_w_cust($1) AS results',[id]);
```

Alternatively just use the query without wrapping it in a function.

Comment: thanks for the reply , im getting syntax error

Comment: thank you after some modification to your query i got it to work , i'll post the final result